# Mongoose filter using both fields of a composite key to perform any upsert operation

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a Product Mongoose schema that I want to perform upserts on. Here is the schema for the Product. It filter for the Product is not working because the rows are not updating.  How do I create the filter query for the composite key? If the query is correct why is the upsert not working

```js
         interface Product {
           _id: {
               productId: number;
               categoryCode: number;
            };
              productName: string;
              category: string;
              quantityInStock: number;
            }

            export default Product;
```

And here is the upsert code:

```js
      async updateOrInsert(products: Products [] ) {
        await Product.bulkWrite(products.map( product => ({
          updateOne: {
              filter: {'_id.productId': product._id.productId, '_id.categoryCode' : product._id.categoryCode},
              update: product,
              upsert: true,
          }
       }))) 
      }
```

Comment: Try `update: {$set: product}` instead of `update: product`

Comment: Thank you, that worked with a small tweak